# Fastest way to remove an element from an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I've coded an algorithm designed to produce a list of the closest triplets from three sorted arrays (one element contributed by each array). The algorithm finds the closest triplet, removes those elements, then repeats the process. The algorithm itself runs quite fast, however the code I'm using to "remove" the elements from each array slows it down significantly. Is there a more efficient method, or is random removal necessarily always O(n)?

My current strategy (effectively identical to `std::move`):

```
for(int i = 6; i < n; ++i)
        array[i] = array[i+1];
```

Where `n` is the size of the array, and 6 is the index of the element to be removed.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove" exactly? Arrays are fixed size, so do you just want the last element to have garbage?

Comment: If you're removing an arbitrary index from an array, the operation is always O(n). I recommend [asking about the actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20asking,trouble%2C%20you%20ask%20about%20Y.) rather than your attempted solution. Likely, the optimization is elsewhere or you're using the wrong data structure to begin with.

Comment: Must these arrays be sorted? If not, move the element at the end of the array into the position of the removed element, then decrease the array "size".

Comment: arrays are slow at element removal (due to need for shifting). If element removal is critical, a linked list often becomes faster.

Comment: [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), although that just moves it to the end.

Comment: @NathanOliver [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) is the right algorithm. But OP's code basically does that.

Comment: @Jeffrey depending on the data size, vector is faster.  For something like an `int`, it's always faster.  https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html

Comment: @NathanOliver I wouldn't have predicted that but in hindsight it makes sense, since traversal _to_ the element to be removed is O(n). Removal by index from list vs vector is just O(n) on different parts. (Vector is O(1) traversal and O(n) removal; list is O(n) traversal and O(1) removal.) Presumably vector gets the advantage because of data locality.

Comment: @KeithMadison, if you really make your algo faster, then, it'll be better to use some advanced ds like multiset...cause, remove from array or list(from an arbitrary position), its always O(n)...

Comment: Warning: In the last iteration of `for(int i = 6; i < n; ++i)` `i` will be `n`-1, so `array[i] = array[i+1];` becomes `array[n-1] = array[n-1+1];` or `array[n-1] = array[n];`, and that `array[n]` is likely to be fatal.

Comment: You say the arrays are sorted, which implies that you want them to keep the same order.  That's a shame, because you're forced to stick with your O(n) solution.  Otherwise as mentioned by others a simple `std::swap(array[6], array[n-1]);` O(1) would suffice.

Comment: Maybe if you show your whole algorithm and explain what problem it solves, we might be able to provide commentary on whether this array-removal paradigm is actually the best way to go.  It could be that there is a much smarter way to solve the main problem.

Comment: I've added the algorithm code. Yes, unfortunately the array must be sorted.

Comment: @MarkRansom Why swap the "removed" value to the end? Simply assign over the removed index.

Comment: `diff` is uninitialized.

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::remove, although that just moves it to the end.` To be super pedantic, it doesn't move anything *to* the end. It moves the non-removed elements *from* the end, leaving the elements in the end in a moved-from state. It also doesn't do removal by index.

Comment: @eerorika good point.  I guess that's why it's better to use the standard algorithms like `std::remove`.

Comment: @KeithMadison, if you're really interested in using some list type ds, then you might read about skiplists....I've added it to my answer and edited the answer a bit...take a look...

Comment: My gut tells me there's probably some kind of back-tracking dynamic programming solution for this that doesn't involve removing elements from arrays.

Comment: *"Assume [...] `p,q,r` are the # of elements in `arr1, arr2, arr3`, respectively"* -- I'd rather not. I would rather see **meaningful** names. Why did you choose random letters instead of something like `size1`, `size2`, and `size3`?

Comment: Your code looks bogus. Since the values of `l`, `p`, `q`, and `r` do not change, your outer loop never ends. Also, two of the three copies of the loop you asked about appear to use the wrong limit (all three use `p`, but it seems like there should be a `q` and `r` in there). I say "appear" because your cryptic variable names make the code harder to read, and the lack of documentation/comments makes guessing the intent challenging.

Comment: Final thought for now: why are you "removing" elements from the arrays? Is the removal needed after the algorithm finishes? Are the arrays just "scratch space" or are they used elsewhere in your program? Would the removal become an essential part of your algorithm after the code is fixed up?

Comment: @nathanoliver your link compares removing a random element from a list (O(n)). Here, it's possible to remove the currently iterated element (O(1)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Fastest way to remove an element from an array?

Note that there is no way to *erase* elements from an array. The size of an array cannot change. So to be clear, we are considering algorithm where the resulting array contains the elements excluding the "removed" value at the beginning of the array, with some irrelevant value in the end.

The algorithm that you show<sup>1</sup> is the optimal one if there is an additional constraint that the order of other elements must not change. It can be slightly improved by using move assignment if the element type is non-trivial, but that doesn't improve asymptotic complexity. There is no need to write the loop, since there is a standard algorithm: `std::move` (the two-argument overload from `<algorithm>`).

If there is no constraint of stable order, then there is a more efficient algorithm: Only write the last element over the "removed" one.

> is random removal [from array] necessarily always O(n)?

Only when the remaining elements need to have a stable order.

---

<sup>1</sup> However, there is a bug in your implementation:

> ```
> for(int i = 6; i < n; ++i)
>     array[i] = array[i+1];
> ```
>
> Where n is the size of the array

If `n` is the size of the array, then `array[n-1+1]` is outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few more options you can consider.

1. Validity masks

You can have an additional array of bool initially everything is set to false to day values are not deleted. To delete the value you set the corresponding bool to true (or the other way if it makes more sense in your code).

This requires a bit of tweaks to the rest of the code to skip values that are marked as deleted.

2. Tombstones

Similar to the solution above, but doesn't require additional memory. If there's a value that it's not used (say all the values are supposed to be positive, then we can use -1) you can set the entry to that value. This also requires tweaks in the rest of the code to skip it.

3. Delayed deletion

This one is a bit more complicated. I'd only use it if iterating over the deleted entries significantly affects performance or complexity.

The idea is to tombsone or mark the entries as deleted. Next time you iterate over the array you also do the swaps. This makes the code kind of complex. The easiest, I think, you can do it is using custom iterators.
This is still O(N), but it's amortized O(1) within the overall algorithm.

Also note that if you do a loop O(N) to find the element to delete and than do another loop O(N) to delete it, then the overall solution is still O(N).